# How to instantiate QSystemTrayIcon?

Tags: python, pyqt, qt5

How do I fix the following error?

```
from PyQt5 import Qt
import sys
app = Qt.QApplication(sys.argv)
systemtray_icon = Qt.QSystemTrayIcon(app,    
Qt.QIcon(r'C:\Users\psivabal\Desktop\o-SWAMI-VIVEKANANDA-facebook.jpg'))
systemtray_icon.show()
systemtray_icon.showMessage('Title', 'Content')
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/psivabal/Desktop/Udacity/My_Examples/Cricket Score trying/TRial.py", line 4, in <module>
    systemtray_icon = Qt.QSystemTrayIcon(app, Qt.QIcon(r'C:\Users\psivabal\Desktop\o-SWAMI-VIVEKANANDA-facebook.jpg'))
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  QSystemTrayIcon(parent: QObject = None): too many arguments
  QSystemTrayIcon(QIcon, parent: QObject = None): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QApplication'
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsystemtrayicon.html#QSystemTrayIcon-1), you should instantiate QSystemTrayIcon as follow:

```
Qt.QSystemTrayIcon(Qt.QIcon(r'icon.jpg'), app)
```

Hint: QObject comes AFTER icon instance